# How to edit the registration page in prestahsop

Tags: prestashop

I want to add a field that is group access in the registration page of my Prestashop store so will any one help me out with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. create all groups via the admin panel
2. modify authentification.tpl in your theme folder :

Add the new field :

```
<input type="radio" name="id_group" id="id_group1" value="1" {if isset($smarty.post.id_group) && $smarty.post.id_group == '1'}checked="checked"{/if} />
<input type="radio" name="id_group" id="id_group2" value="2" {if isset($smarty.post.id_group) && $smarty.post.id_group == '2'}checked="checked"{/if} />
```

1. Modify the controller AuthController.php (where the user is saved)

$id_group = (Tools::getIsset('id_group')) ? Tools::getValue('id_group') : 1;

On the official forum i found this : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/59057-solved-change-user-group-after-registration/

I hope it can help.

Good luck

Comment: actually i want to assign group during the registration page to differentiate wholesaler and regular customer.